# TypeError: command.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I'm kinda new to coding and i cannot figure this out. im trying to add permission handler and when i run a slash command, it responds within the error given below.

error:

```
D:\VS Code\######\events\interactionCreate.js:9
        command.run(client, inter)
                ^

TypeError: command.run is not a function
```

code (interactionCreate):

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Message, Interaction } = require("discord.js")
const client = require("../index").client

client.on('interactionCreate', async inter => {
    if(inter.isCommand()) {
        const command = client.commands.get(inter.commandName);
        if(!command) return;
   
        command.run(client, inter)
        if (command.help?.permission) {
    const authorPerms = inter.channel.permissionsFor(inter.member);
    if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permission)) {
        const noPerms = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RED')
            .setDescription(`bruh no perms for ya: ${command.permission}`)
        return inter.editReply({embeds: [noPerms], ephemeral: true})
        .then((sent) =>{
            setTimeout(() => {
                sent.delete()
            }, 10000)
        })
return;
    }
}

}
}
)
```

this is how one of my command file looks like, its a handler which goes "commands > moderation > ban.js"

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (client, inter) => {

    const user = inter.options.getUser('user')
    let BanReason = inter.options.getString('reason')
    const member = inter.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
    if(!BanReason) reason = 'No reason provided.'

            const existEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#2f3136')
            .setDescription('<:pending:961309491784196166> The member does not exist in the server.')

            const bannedEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#46b281')
            .setDescription(`<:success:961309491935182909> Successfully banned **${user.tag}** from the server with the reason of: **${BanReason}**.`)

            const failedEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ec4e4b')
            .setDescription(`<:failed:961309491763228742> Cannot ban **${user.tag}**. Please make sure I have permission to ban.`)


    if(!member) return inter.reply({ embeds: [existEmbed]})

    try {
        await inter.guild.members.ban(member, { reasons: BanReason })
    } catch(e) {
        return inter.reply({ embeds: [failedEmbed]})
    }

    inter.reply({ embeds: [bannedEmbed]})
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'ban',
    permission: 'BAN_MEMBERS'
}
```

btw `inter = interaction`

Comment: It means your `command` doesn't have a `run` method. How does your command file look like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/LzCX1WiE or check the edited post

Comment: Can you show me how did you define the `client.commands` collection?

Comment: One of your commands doesn't have a run function